# Angular State Dropdown Bound to Country Select

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to have a contextual state dropdown menu that is bound to the country so that only the relevant states display.

I have looked at these two answers for a solution to my implementation.

> [Angularjs trigger country state dependency](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18173717/angularjs-trigger-country-state-dependency)
>
> [angularjs dependant dropdown option value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28593642/angularjs-dependant-dropdown-option-value)

But I cannot get them to work and am missing something.

My preferred solution would use some existing ng filter, but I understand that only works on arrays and not objects

```
 <select ng-model="user.state" ng-options="state.name for state in states track by state.id | filter:state.countryid = user.country.id">
```

I tried converting the object to an array, but that did not seem to work.

I could create a custom filter, but I am hoping to avoid that.

```
 <select ng-model="user.state" ng-options="state.name for state in states track by state.id | customStateFilter:user.country.id">
```

It seems like there should be some way to get ng-options to work without modifying the data.

Is there an existing Angular filter that works on objects or a way to do conditional logic to filter out the objects dynamically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a few issues here (in addition to a mismatch of `state.countryid` and `country.id`):

**First**, `track by` comes after the filter (or, in other words, filter comes right after the array, since it filters the array).

**Second**, you are right - the built-in filter `filter` only works on arrays, not objects. For objects, you'd need a custom filter.

And **lastly**, `filter` filter doesn't accept an expression to evaluate (`filter:state.countryid = user.country.id`, not to mention that this "expression" that you tried to provide doesn't compare `===`, but assigns `=`). `filter` accepts as a parameter either a `string` - to match any property against, an `Object` specifying which property to match against which value, or a predicate function.

In your case, an object is what you need.

To put this thing together you get:

```
<select ng-model="selectedState"
        ng-options="state.name for state in states | filter: {countryid: user.country.id}:true track by state.id">
  <option value="">select state</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Thanks, I see the syntax for object expressions now. That makes sense.

Comment: If anyone has this same problem, you will also want to make the filter an exact match by adding :true like, "filter: {countryid: user.country.id}:true" otherwise you will get any match that contains part of the number

Comment: @User970008, that's correct - I'll update the answer.